# Collection element is overridden while adding elements in for loop

Tags: python, json, geojson

I have a `geojson` in which there could be features of type multi-polygon or polygon. If it's multi-polygon I want to explode it to polygons.

```
{
     "type": "FeatureCollection",
     "features": [
         {
             "type": "Feature",
             "properties": {
                 "id": "86aba1ae-80e2-49d4-ab32-c2744a3b4bf4"
             },
             "geometry": {
                 "type": "MultiPolygon",
                 "coordinates": [
                     [...],
                     [...]
                 ]
             }
         }
      ]
}
```

For e.g. above `geojson` should create 2 features which is working fine but I also want to generate unique `id` for each of them which I am doing with `str(uuid.uuid4())`. This gives unique id for each `xfeature` but when it is appended to `output` collection, the second one always overrides the first one and the ids are duplicated. I can't find the reason why this is happening and how to solve it.

```
js = open('test.geojson', 'r').read()
gj = json.loads(js)

output = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": []}

for feature in gj['features']:
    if ((feature['geometry'] is not None) 
        and (feature['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiPolygon')):
        for poly in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
            xfeature = {"type": "Feature", 'properties': feature['properties'], 
                        "geometry": {"type": "Polygon"}}
            xfeature['properties']['id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
            xfeature['geometry']['coordinates'] = poly
            output['features'].append(xfeature)
    else:
        output['features'].append(feature)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `'properties': feature['properties']` in the line

```
    xfeature = {"type": "Feature", 'properties': feature['properties'], "geometry": {"type": "Polygon"}}
```

you have to clone it.

Use deepcopy in order to do that - https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html